# How can I log a struct automatically by zerolog?

Tags: go, logging

I am using `zerolog` for logging in a go application. I'd like to log a map (json) and find a way:

```golang
log.Info().
    Str("foo", "bar").
    Dict("dict", zerolog.Dict().
        Str("bar", "baz").
        Int("n", 1),
    ).Msg("hello world")

// Output: {"level":"info","time":1494567715,"foo":"bar","dict":{"bar":"baz","n":1},"message":"hello world"}
```

in above example, I need to specify each `key-value` pair in `zerolog.Dict()` method. I wonder whether there is an automatic way to log a `struct`.

For example, I have a struct like:

```
type Message struct {
    AWS_REGION     string `json:"region"`
    LOG_LEVEL      string `json:"level"`
    STAGE          string `json:"stage"`
    REQUEST_ID     string `json:"requestId"`
}
```

I am looking for a way to pass `Message` instance to

```
msg := Message{ ... }
zerolog.Dict("message", msg)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the [`Interface`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/rs/zerolog#Context.Interface) method.

[Example](https://go.dev/play/p/MS78ykhezjc)

However, note that `Interface` uses reflection for serialisation, so code shortness comes at a cost of performance

Comment: cool thanks for the help. Do you know whether I can put the `dict` field into root level fields?